# Control sequence for upper case letter

Tags: unix, readline, touch-typing

I'm trying to improve my touch-typing which is very low both on accuracy and speed.

I've noticed that I have a great difficulty regarding upper case letters.
I often have to leave the home row or I always mistype if I'm stretching my pinky to reach shift.

I had the same problems with backspace that I solved by starting using ^H instead, my control is in capslock so I can perform most readline shortcuts easily and I can easily correct mistakes without leaving the home row.

Maybe there is a way to escape an uppercase letter? Just like we can escape sequences with ^V, or like we can transpose the characters in cursor with ^T. There is a way to uppercase the character in cursor or something?

**Edit**: for clarification, as asked:

I'm currently in macOS, the default shell is zsh but I can easily switch for another one where I can achieve this.
So I'm really accepting any possible solutions as I can try to test the same system-wide later.

On most apps on macOS I can use control sequences for line editing just like if I was in terminal, and I guess that macOS uses readline to achieve that, and for some applications I also use rlwrap which is a wrapper for readline, that's why I could probably benefit from a readline related solution as well.

If you know a solution for any shell, it'll be useful as I can start using this shell instead.

Comment: Do you want a system-wide solution? or in readline? (you used the tag). I think what you want is possible and relatively easy in the command line of Bash 5, not so easy (when multi-byte characters are involved) in Bash 4. What I have in mind is specific to Bash, so not even readline-wide. Please [edit] and state the desired scope and the minimal acceptable scope.

Comment: Thanks Kamil. I have a wide acceptable scope, I'm looking forward to hear about your Bash 5 solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do in Bash 5:

```bsh
_up() {
 [ "$READLINE_POINT" -lt 1 ] && return 0
 local char
 char="${READLINE_LINE:$((READLINE_POINT-1)):1}"
 READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$((READLINE_POINT-1))}${char^}${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}" 
}

bind -x '"\C-x\C-u":_up'
```

From now on <kbd>Ctrl <kbd>x</kbd><kbd>u</kbd></kbd> will convert the character before the text cursor to uppercase. The idea is you use the combination just after you type a lowercase character.

Bind the function to some less cumbersome combination.

`READLINE_LINE` is a variable that allows us to retrieve and/or modify the content of the command line. `READLINE_POINT` is a variable that allows us to know and/or set where in the line the text cursor is.

**The method is quite limited**, it works only in the command line of Bash. It should work well in Bash 5.

Bash 4 supports `READLINE_LINE` and `READLINE_POINT` but the latter variable uses bytes, while in Bash 5 it uses characters. This means you can use the function in Bash 4 and it will work in many cases, multi-byte characters will confuse it though. Patching the function so it works well with multi-byte characters in Bash 4 may not be trivial.